# Setting attributes recursively

Tags: php

I have a following chain of classes:

```
class A extends Model {
  public $first;
  public $b;
  public function __construct() {
    $this -> b = new B();
  }
}

class B extends Model {
  public $c;
  public function __construct() {
    $this -> c = new C();
  }
}

class C extends Model {
  public $foo;
}
```

And I want to write a function that will set an attribute values based on some parameter, for example if I will call it on object `A` and pass `array('b_c_foo' => 'something')`  to it, I want `$a -> b -> c -> foo = 'something'` to be set.

For example:

```
$a = new A();
$params = array(
    'first' => 'first',
    'b_c_foo' => 'something'
);
$a -> fillAttributes($params);
var_dump($a); // here A object should have first == 'fist', and b -> c -> foo == 'something'
```

I have written such a function for the `A` class only, it's easy because I can just find array indexes and set it to `A` class like `$this -> {$index} = $value;`, but it's not that easy if the number of calls is dynamic.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
public function fillAttributes(array $params)
{
    foreach ($params as $attributeName => $attributeValue) {
        $rootObject = $this;

        foreach(explode('_', $attributeName) as $proprietyName) {
              if (property_exists($rootObject, $proprietyName)) {
                  if (is_object($rootObject->$proprietyName)) {
                      $rootObject = $rootObject->$proprietyName;
                  }
              }
        }

        $rootObject->$proprietyName = $attributeValue;
    }
}
```

Basically you `explode` the string and check if a propriety with that name exists and it's not an object. Only then you set the value.